# Is there a way to not have to initialize arrays twice?

Tags: arrays, initialization, rust, array-initialization

I need to initialize each element of an array to a non-constant expression. Can I do that without having to first initialize each element of the array to some meaningless expression? Here's an example of what I'd like to be able to do:

```
fn foo(xs: &[i32; 1000]) {
    let mut ys: [i32; 1000];

    for (x, y) in xs.iter().zip(ys.iter_mut()) {
        *y = *x / 3;
    }
    // ...
}
```

This code gives the compile-time error:

```
error[E0381]: borrow of possibly uninitialized variable: `ys`
 --> src/lib.rs:4:33
  |
4 |     for (x, y) in xs.iter().zip(ys.iter_mut()) {
  |                                 ^^ use of possibly uninitialized `ys`
```

To fix the problem, I need to change the first line of the function to initialize the elements of `ys` with some dummy values like so:

```
let mut ys: [i32; 1000] = [0; 1000];
```

Is there any way to omit that extra initialization? Wrapping everything in an `unsafe` block doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In some cases, you can use [`std::mem::MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html):

```rust
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;

fn main() {
    let mut ys: MaybeUninit<[i32; 1000]> = MaybeUninit::uninit();
}
```

Removing the `MaybeUninit` wrapper via [`assume_init`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#method.assume_init) is unsafe because accessing uninitialized values is undefined behavior in Rust and the compiler can no longer guarantee that every value of `ys` will be initialized before it is read.

Your specific case is [one of the examples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#initializing-an-array-element-by-element) in the `MaybeUninit` docs; read it for a discussion about the safety of this implementation:

```rust
use std::mem::{self, MaybeUninit};

fn foo(xs: &[i32; 1000]) {
    // I copied this code from Stack Overflow without
    // reading why it is or is not safe.
    let ys: [i32; 1000] = {
        let mut ys: [MaybeUninit<i32>; 1000] = unsafe { MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init() };

        let mut xs = xs.into_iter();

        for y in &mut ys[..] {
            if let Some(x) = xs.next().copied() {
                *y = MaybeUninit::new(x / 3);
            }
        }

        unsafe { mem::transmute(ys) }
    };
    // ...
}
```

---

You [cannot collect into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26757355/155423), but if you had a `Vec` instead, you could do:

```
let ys: Vec<_> = xs.iter().map(|&x| x / 3).collect();
```

For your specific problem, you could also clone the incoming array and then mutate it:

```
let mut ys = xs.clone();
for y in ys.iter_mut() { *y = *y / 3 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/array/fn.from_fn.html

```
fn foo(xs: &[i32; 1000]) {
    let ys: [i32; 1000] = array::from_fn(|i| (xs[i] / 3) as i32);
```