# Rust Version of C code

Tags: rust

Very simple, how can I do the same thing I would do in C in Rust.

So C code:

```
extern mps_res_t mps_arena_create_k(mps_arena_t *);

mps_arena_t arena;
res = mps_arena_create_k(&arena);
```

In C this works, so in rust I did:

```
extern "C" {
    pub fn mps_arena_create_k(arg1: *mut mps_arena_t) -> mps_res_t;
} // created by rust_bindgen

unsafe {
   let mut arena : *mut mps_arena_t; 
   res = mps_arena_create_k(arena);
}
```

The problem is that the compiler complains:

```
error: use of possibly uninitialized variable: `arena`
```

Im not a good C programmer but this pattern seams common, how do I do it in rust?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185618/is-there-a-way-to-not-have-to-initialize-arrays-twice and by the way Rust hasn't been standardized yet, I don't know if it make sense to use Rust right now for such "sensitive" stuff or if it does at all; If I were you I would wait for a standard Rust 1.0 .

Comment: Please ask your rust-question in english, not in partial snippets of C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`std::mem::uninitialized`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/mem/fn.uninitialized.html) to leave a variable uninitialized for a while:

```
let mut arena: mps_arena_t;
let res;
unsafe {
    arena = std::mem::uninitialized();
    res = mps_arena_create_k(&mut arena);
}
```

Note that `arena` should be typed as `mps_arena_t` and not `*mut mps_arena_t` (presumably a transliteration error?). You also need to keep `arena` out of the `unsafe` block (hence the separated `let` and assignment), unless you are going to destroy it soon.

Comment: Thanks, I mad it *mut mps_arena_t because otherwise I could not get it threw the type checker. But your version works too. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The C statement `mps_arena_t arena;` is a declaration of a local variable, with the appropriate memory on the stack, if I recall correctly, undefined. (It may be zeroed or it may be uninitialised.)

In Rust, the equivalent statement would be `let mut arena: mps_arena_t = unsafe { std::mem::uninitialized() };`. You would then call `mps_arena_create_k(&mut arena)` (`&mut T` coerces to `*mut T` implicitly).

Comment: Deklaring things like this is not a problem. But before its first use, the compiler has to be sure that it got initialized.