# Calling a procedure from a Vec<proc() -> uint>

Tags: rust

While trying to answer on [Rust array of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491196/rust-array-of-functions#27492400) (it's been answered with a great answer), I've coined the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a : Vec<proc() -> uint>;
    for i in range(0u, 11) {
        a[i] = proc(){i};
    }
    println!("{} {} {}", a[1](), a[5](), a[9]());
}
```

Please ignore the fact that `proc` is being deprecated, I just figured out that this is what should be used instead of closures (I didn't know about `move` and unboxed closures at that time).

However, I was not able to call elements of a vector due the following:

```
 <anon>:6:26: 6:30 error: cannot move out of dereference (dereference is implicit, due to indexing)
 <anon>:6     println!("{} {} {}", a[1](), a[5](), a[9]());
```

What this error means? Shouldn't it just return `uint`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`proc()` were closures that could only be used once, and thus calling them consumed them.

In your situation, this would imply moving the closure out of the `Vec<>` in order to consume it, which is not possible as indexing is the dereferencing of a `&` pointer, which only allow immutable access.

Comment: Ah, I see - `could be used only onced`! Thanks!