# How to create a vector of boxed closures in Rust?

Tags: rust, closures, boxing

Previously [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491196/rust-array-of-functions) was asked about creating an array of functions where the functions returned integers from a range. The final solution was to do a map/collect into a `Vec<_>`.

I have a similar yet different situation where I have closures with the same signature but different implementations. I tried this:

```
let xs: Vec<_> = vec![
    move |(x, y)| (y, x),
    move |(x, y)| (1 - y, 1 - x),
];
```

The error I get back:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:9
  |
4 |         move |(x, y)| (1 - y, 1 - x),
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected closure, found a different closure
  |
  = note: expected type `[closure@src/main.rs:3:9: 3:29]`
             found type `[closure@src/main.rs:4:9: 4:37]`
  = note: no two closures, even if identical, have the same type
  = help: consider boxing your closure and/or using it as a trait object
```

I tried boxing:

```
let xs: Vec<_> = vec![
    Box::new(move |x: u8, y: u8| (y, x)),
    Box::new(move |x: u8, y: u8| (1 - y, 1 - x)),
];
```

I get back the same error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:18
  |
4 |         Box::new(move |x: u8, y: u8| (1 - y, 1 - x)),
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected closure, found a different closure
  |
  = note: expected type `[closure@src/main.rs:3:18: 3:44]`
             found type `[closure@src/main.rs:4:18: 4:52]`
  = note: no two closures, even if identical, have the same type
  = help: consider boxing your closure and/or using it as a trait object
```

What is the right way to box closures so that they can be put into a vector (or an array)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that type inference has kicked in before you wanted it to. Conceptually, it's like this:

```
let mut xs: Vec<_> = Vec::new();
xs.push(Type1);
xs.push(Type2);
```

When the first value is seen, the type of the `Vec`'s elements is inferred to be of that type. The second element then causes a mismatch.

Even when you `Box` the values, you have the same problem:

```
let mut xs: Vec<_> = Vec::new();
xs.push(Box::new(Type1));
xs.push(Box::new(Type2));
```

Looking at it another way, you never actually created a trait object. You have a `Box<ConcreteType>`, not a `Box<dyn Trait>`.

The solution is to cast the boxed concrete types to the *boxed trait object*:

```
let mut xs: Vec<_> = Vec::new();
xs.push(Box::new(Type1) as Box<dyn Trait>);
xs.push(Box::new(Type2) as Box<dyn Trait>);
```

The *second* `push` can have the type coerced automatically, so you can choose to leave the `as` bit off of that line.

Rolling this back up to the original problem:

```
let xs: Vec<_> = vec![
    Box::new(move |(x, y)| (y, x)) as Box<dyn Fn((i32, i32)) -> (i32, i32)>,
    Box::new(move |(x, y)| (1 - y, 1 - x)),
];
```

Or you can avoid the inference at all by specifying the type on the variable, my preferred style for this:

```
let xs: Vec<Box<dyn Fn((i32, i32)) -> (i32, i32)>> = vec![
    Box::new(move |(x, y)| (y, x)),
    Box::new(move |(x, y)| (1 - y, 1 - x)),
];
```

Answer (score 5):

You should read the suggestion in the error message as *"consider boxing your closure and using it as a trait object, or using it just as a trait object"*.

Using trait object references without boxing them will not work here because nothing owns the closures. The references in the vector would outlive the closures:

```
// This fails
let xs: Vec<&Fn((i32, i32)) -> (i32, i32)> = vec![ 
    &move |(x, y)| (y, x), 
    &move |(x, y)| (1 - y, 1 - x),
];
```

The vector needs to take ownership of the closures, which is where boxing the trait objects comes into play:

```
let xs: Vec<Box<Fn((i32, i32)) -> (i32, i32)>> = vec![ 
    Box::new(move |(x, y)| (y, x)), 
    Box::new(move |(x, y)| (1 - y, 1 - x)),
];
```

This explicitly tells the compiler that the vector can contain boxes of any closure with the same interface.

Comment: Although this answer shows the correct end code, the OP *already* tried boxing the closures, as shown in the question. Lifetimes also do not play a part in the problem.

Comment: @Shepmaster What lifetimes are you referring to?

Comment: That was a poor choice of words on my part. I was referring to your statement "the closures are temporary and the vector would outlive them". They are not *temporary*, the `Vec` would own them, it's just that you cannot own the concrete value and have the `Vec`'s type be a reference.

Comment: @Shepmaster The error message seems to suggest the problem could be solved without boxing. My intent was to point out why this fails, but forgot to insert the `&`s. In that case there is actually a lifetime issue.