# What is the difference between a Rust closure and a Haskell lambda?

Tags: haskell, lambda, rust, closures

Recently I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49012277/how-to-create-a-vector-of-boxed-closures-in-rust) about how to put a bunch of closures with the same signature into a vector in Rust. Coming from a Haskell background, it seemed a bit complicated, with Rust closures each having their own unique types and needing a trait to represent them. In Haskell, a lambda is typed by its signature and if the signature is the same, the type is the same.

Is there a semantic difference between a Rust closure and a Haskell lambda function that makes for these differences?

Comment: Does Haskell monomorphize their closures? I know there's some aspects around stream fusion...

Comment: @Shepmaster I am not an expert in Haskell, and only a beginner in Rust, which is why I'd like to know.

Comment: @Shepmaster No, Haskell closures are no more monomorphic than they need to be (with one occasionally annoying exception for top-level definitions, the monomorphism restriction, and even that can be turned off with a compiler flag).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rust's choice of using distinct types has two performance benefits:

- The compiler can stack allocate the data you close over (or embed it into the containing data structure)
- Since it knows which function the closure references at compile time it can statically dispatch the call and even inline the call.

You can also choose to use `Box<Fn>` instead. That costs a heap allocation and results in an indirect call, but in exchange there is only one type per signature.

Comment: FTR, Haskell lambdas can very often be inlined too. It just usually requires that the higher-order function you _pass_ the lambda to is inlined first, which can be a bit of a code bloat (but this is actually quite similar to what C++ and Rust do when instantiating templates over a lambda's type).