# Rust append a closure to a vector

Tags: types, rust, closures

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49012277/how-to-create-a-vector-of-boxed-closures-in-rust) says, you can create a vector of closures like this:

```
let mut xs: Vec<Box<dyn Fn((i32, i32)) -> (i32, i32)>> = vec![
    Box::new(move |(x, y)| (y, x)),
    Box::new(move |(x, y)| (1 - y, 1 - x)),
];
```

But why can't you append to it using:

```
xs.append(Box::new(move |(x, y)| (2 - y, 2 - x)));
```

This raises the error:

```
    |
162 |         xs.append(Box::new(move |(x, y)| (2 - y, 2 - x)));
    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected mutable reference, found struct `std::boxed::Box`                                                            
    |
    = note: expected mutable reference `&mut std::vec::Vec<std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::Fn((i32, i32)) -> (i32, i32)>>`                                      
                          found struct `std::boxed::Box<[closure@src/lib.rs:162:22: 162:50]>`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The names for the methods in rust are different than in languages. You seem to have the right idea but [`Vec::append`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.append) function adds the elements of another vector into the target instance.

The method you should use is [`Vec::push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.push), which pushes an element to the back of the vector.

You can see from the error that it was expecting you to provide a `&mut std::vec::Vec<std::boxed::Box<...>>` but received a `std::boxed::Box<...>`

```
note: expected mutable reference `&mut std::vec::Vec<std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::Fn((i32, i32)) -> (i32, i32)>>`                                      
                          found struct `std::boxed::Box<[closure@src/lib.rs:162:22: 162:50]>`
```

Comment: @Kryptomatrix No worries!