# How to convert code that uses the Read trait to use the Iterator trait instead?

Tags: iterator, rust

I have some code which parses files, very similar to the following:

```
use std::io::Cursor;
use std::io::Result;
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
   let v1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
   let mut c1 = Cursor::new(v1); // *

    println!("{:?}", read_one(&mut c1)); // 1
    println!("{:?}", read_three(&mut c1)); // 2, 3, 4     
    println!("{:?}", read_one(&mut c1)); // 5
    println!("{:?}", read_one(&mut c1)); // eof
}

fn read_one<R: Read>(r: &mut R) -> Result<u8> {
  let mut buf = [0; 1];
  r.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
  Ok(buf[0])
}

fn read_three<R: Read>(r: &mut R) -> Result<[u8; 3]> {
  let mut buf = [0; 3];
  r.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
  Ok(buf)
}
```

Here, `read_one` and `read_three` take a `Read` trait, get some bytes off of it, and return the result. I can then read the bytes piece by piece.

I'd like to convert this code to using an iterator instead. That is, have the `*` line be

```
let mut i1 = v1.iter();
```

Trying this, I ran into problems where I couldn't find functions to easily extract a number of items (analogous to `read_exact`) or otherwise partially process an iterator. It seems most of the iterator functions are designed to consume the content entirely.

Is the iterator just a bad tool for this or am I using it wrong? If the latter, how do I convert this code to use iterators instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write *almost* the same thing with iterators. The problem you'll run into is that arrays are difficult to work with, because they don't (as of December 2017) implement `FromIterator`. As user1541501 [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48032072/3650362), the simplest solution is to `collect()` into a `Vec` instead:

```
fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let mut c1 = v1.into_iter();

    println!("{:?}", read_one(&mut c1)); // 1
    println!("{:?}", read_three(&mut c1)); // 2, 3, 4
    println!("{:?}", read_one(&mut c1)); // 5
    println!("{:?}", read_one(&mut c1)); // eof
}

fn read_one<I: Iterator<Item = u8>>(i: &mut I) -> Option<u8> {
    i.next()
}

fn read_three<I: Iterator<Item = u8>>(i: &mut I) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Vec<u8>> {
    let buf: Vec<u8> = i.take(3).collect();
    if buf.len() == 3 {
        Ok(buf)
    } else {
        Err(buf)
    }
}
```

Arrays also don't implement `IntoIterator`, so I turned `v1` into a `Vec<u8>` to call `v1.into_iter()`. You could write `v1.iter().cloned()` instead.

The other significant change I made was to make `read_one` return `Option` instead of `io::Result`, and make `read_three` return `Result<Vec<u8>, Vec<u8>>`. That's because iterators can only fail by running out of data. (If `read_three` fails, the `Err` variant contains the collected elements.)

Answer (score 3):

You can make your own trait for that

```
use std::io::{Error, ErrorKind, Result};

trait ReadExact {
    fn read_exact(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<()>;
}

impl<T> ReadExact for T
where
    T: Iterator<Item = u8>,
{
    fn read_exact(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<()> {
        for p in buf {
            if let Some(b) = self.next() {
                *p = b;
            } else {
                return Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::UnexpectedEof, "Iterator exhausted"));
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1599057980a01abea068adf6e92a00ca&version=stable)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the explanation of why you can't [collect into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757355/how-do-i-collect-into-an-array)

If you still want to use an iterator you can change return type to Vec
and call 
`r.take(n).collect();`

This, however, will be a little bit slower.