# Why do I get the error "no method named collect found for type Option"?

Tags: rust

I'm doing the [Exercism](https://exercism.io/) Rust problem in which a string has arbitrary length, but could be null, and needs to be classified based on its last two graphemes.

My understanding is that `Option` is used to account for something that could be null, or could be not null, when this is unknown at compile time, so I've tried this:

```
extern crate unicode_segmentation;

use unicode_segmentation::UnicodeSegmentation;

pub fn reply(message: &str) -> &str {
    let message_opt: Option<[&str; 2]> = message.graphemes(true).rev().take(2).nth(0).collect();
}
```

My understanding of which, is that the right hand side will give an array of two `&str`s, if the string is non zero in length, or will return none, and the left hand side will store it as an option (so that I can later match on `Some` or `None`)

The error is:

```
no method named 'collect' found for type std::option::Option<&str> in the current scope
```

This doesn't make sense to me, as I (think) I'm trying to collect the output of an iterator, I am not *collecting* an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message isn't lying to you. `Option` does **not** have a method called `collect`.

> I (think) I'm trying to collect the output of an iterator

[`Iterator::nth`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth) returns an `Option`. `Option` does not implement `Iterator`; you cannot call `collect` on it.

> `Option<[&str; 2]>`

You can't do this, either:

- [How do I collect into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26757355/155423)

---

I'd write this as

```
let mut graphemes = message.graphemes(true).fuse();

let message_opt = match (graphemes.next_back(), graphemes.next_back()) {
    (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some([a, b]),
    _ => None,
};
```

Comment: Haha, I didn't think it was lying to me :)
Oh, I thought the option referred to the left hand side, and that's why I was confused.