# Why does spawning threads using Iterator::map not run the threads in parallel?

Tags: multithreading, functional-programming, rust

I wrote a simple multithreaded application in Rust to add the numbers from 1 to x. (I know there is a formula for this, but the point was to write some multi threaded code in Rust, not to get the outcome.)
It worked fine, but after I refactored it to a more functional style instead of imperative, there was no more speedup from multithreading. When inspecting the CPU usage, it appears that only one core is used of my 4 core / 8 thread CPU. The original code has 790% CPU usage, while the refactored version only has 99%.

The original code:

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let mut handles: Vec<thread::JoinHandle<u64>> = Vec::with_capacity(8);

    const thread_count: u64 = 8;
    const batch_size: u64 = 20000000;

    for thread_id in 0..thread_count {
        handles.push(thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut sum = 0_u64;

            for i in thread_id * batch_size + 1_u64..(thread_id + 1) * batch_size + 1_u64 {
                sum += i;
            }

            sum
        }));
    }

    let mut total_sum = 0_u64;

    for handle in handles.into_iter() {
        total_sum += handle.join().unwrap();
    }
    println!("{}", total_sum);
}
```

The refactored code:

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    const THREAD_COUNT: u64 = 8;
    const BATCH_SIZE: u64 = 20000000;

    // spawn threads that calculate a part of the sum
    let handles = (0..THREAD_COUNT).map(|thread_id| {
        thread::spawn(move ||
            // calculate the sum of all numbers from assigned to this thread
            (thread_id * BATCH_SIZE + 1 .. (thread_id + 1) * BATCH_SIZE + 1)
                .fold(0_u64,|sum, number| sum + number))
    });

    // add the parts of the sum together to get the total sum
    let sum = handles.fold(0_u64, |sum, handle| sum + handle.join().unwrap());

    println!("{}", sum);
}
```

the outputs of the programs are the same (12800000080000000), but the refactored version is 5-6 times slower.

It appears that iterators are lazily evaluated. How can I force the entire iterator to be evaluated? I tried to collect it into an array of type `[thread::JoinHandle<u64>; THREAD_COUNT as usize]`, but I then I get the following error:

```
  --> src/main.rs:14:7
   |
14 |     ).collect::<[thread::JoinHandle<u64>; THREAD_COUNT as usize]>();
   |       ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `[std::thread::JoinHandle<u64>; 8]` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=std::thread::JoinHandle<u64>>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<std::thread::JoinHandle<u64>>` is not implemented for `[std::thread::JoinHandle<u64>; 8]`
```

Collecting into a vector does work, but that seems like a weird solution, because the size is known up front. Is there a better way then using a vector?

Comment: [How do I collect into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757355/how-do-i-collect-into-an-array) — TL;DR you cant easily. Use `ArrayVec` or just stick with a `Vec`, which will only do one allocation anyway since the length of the iterator is known.

Answer (score 7):

Iterators in Rust are lazy, so your threads are not started until `handles.fold` tries to access the corresponding element of the iterator. Basically what happens is:

1. `handles.fold` tries to access the first element of the iterator.
2. The first thread is started.
3. `handles.fold` calls its closure, which calls `handle.join()` for the first thread.
4. `handle.join` waits for the first thread to finish.
5. `handles.fold` tries to access the second element of the iterator.
6. The second thread is started.
7. and so on.

You should collect the handles into a vector before folding the result:

```
let handles: Vec<_> = (0..THREAD_COUNT)
    .map(|thread_id| {
        thread::spawn(move ||
            // calculate the sum of all numbers from assigned to this thread
            (thread_id * BATCH_SIZE + 1 .. (thread_id + 1) * BATCH_SIZE + 1)
                .fold(0_u64,|sum, number| sum + number))
    })
    .collect();
```

Or you could use a crate like [Rayon](https://crates.io/crates/rayon) which provides parallel iterators.

Comment: Ah thanks. This is exactly what I thought. (I was writing the edit while you posted this.) I think I'll have a look at rayon.