# How to change str into array in rust

Tags: rust

how would I go about changing a str into a array of bytes or chars?

for example:
`"1.1.1.1" -> ["1", ".", "1", ".", "1", ".", "1"]`

The string is an ip so no usual characters.

I have tried doing `try_into()` but got

```
expected array `[u8; 10]`
  found struct `std::slice::Iter<'_, u8>`
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Edit:
In my use case I have a struct called Player:

```
struct Player {
    cards: [i32, 2],
    chips: u32,
    ip: [u8; 10],
    folded: bool,
    hand: u8,
}
```

And I'd like to set the id to a string that would be received and store it as a array. Ideally the struct would `impl` copy, so a `vec` can't be used.

a player being made:

```
Player {
   cards: [4,5],
   chips: 500,
   ip: "localhost", // how to change this to an array
   folded: false,
   hand: 0,
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by into an array? Returning an array of variable size is not possible in rust. Would a vec of chars solve your problem?

Comment: Is the string hardcoded? Because you can do `b"1.1.1.1"` to make an array which contains the bytes. Otherwise I'd look into the `.chars()` method.

Comment: @user1937198 the str is of fixed length, I have a struct with a field that contains an array, otherwise I'd use a vec. I can't use a vec since it is inside a struct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I collect into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757355/how-do-i-collect-into-an-array)

Comment: @E_net4likesfun thanks, so it seems it isn't possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html) is a special case for a [`slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) type. And unlike an array it does not have a known size at compile-time (i.e. calculated dynamically during program execution), therefore there is no infallible conversion. But you can manually craft an array and iterate over `str` to get it bytes:

```rust
let s = "1.1.1.1";

let mut your_array = [0u8; 10];

if s.len() != your_array.len() {
    // handle this somehow
}

s.bytes()
    .zip(your_array.iter_mut())
    .for_each(|(b, ptr)| *ptr = b);
```