# How to generate a random String of alphanumeric chars?

Tags: string, random, utf-8, rust, char

The first part of the question is probably pretty common and there are enough code samples that explain how to generate a random string of alphanumerics. The piece of code I use is from [here](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/algorithms/randomness.html#create-random-passwords-from-a-set-of-alphanumeric-characters).

```rust
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};
use rand::distributions::Alphanumeric;

fn main() {
    let rand_string: String = thread_rng()
        .sample_iter(&Alphanumeric)
        .take(30)
        .collect();

    println!("{}", rand_string);
}
```

This piece of code does however not compile, (note: I'm on nightly):

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `String` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `u8`
 --> src/main.rs:8:10
  |
8 |         .collect();
  |          ^^^^^^^ value of type `String` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=u8>`
  |
  = help: the trait `FromIterator<u8>` is not implemented for `String`
```

Ok, the elements that are generated are of type `u8`. So I guess this is an array or vector of `u8`:

```rust
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};
use rand::distributions::Alphanumeric;

fn main() {
    let r = thread_rng()
        .sample_iter(&Alphanumeric)
        .take(30)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let s = String::from_utf8_lossy(&r);
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

And this compiles and works!

```
2dCsTqoNUR1f0EzRV60IiuHlaM4TfK
```

All good, except that I would like to ask if someone could explain what exactly happens regarding the types and how this can be optimised.

**Questions**

1. `.sample_iter(&Alphanumeric)` produces `u8` and not `char`s?
2. How can I avoid the second variable `s` and directly interpret an `u8` as a utf-8 character? I guess the representation in memory would not change at all?
3. The length of these strings should always be 30. How can I optimise the heap allocation of a `Vec` away? Also they could actually be `char[]` instead of `String`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `.sample_iter(&Alphanumeric)` produces u8 and not chars?

Yes, this was changed in rand v0.8. [You can see in the docs for 0.7.3](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.3/rand/distributions/struct.Alphanumeric.html):

```rust
impl Distribution<char> for Alphanumeric
```

[But then in the docs for 0.8.0](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.0/rand/distributions/struct.Alphanumeric.html):

```rust
impl Distribution<u8> for Alphanumeric
```

> How can I avoid the second variable `s` and directly interpret an `u8` as a utf-8 character? I guess the representation in memory would not change at all?

There are a couple of ways to do this, the most obvious being to just cast every `u8` to a `char`:

```rust
let s: String = thread_rng()
    .sample_iter(&Alphanumeric)
    .take(30)
    .map(|x| x as char)
    .collect();
```

Or, using the [`From<u8>` instance of `char`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#impl-From%3Cu8%3E):

```rust
let s: String = thread_rng()
    .sample_iter(&Alphanumeric)
    .take(30)
    .map(char::from)
    .collect();
```

Of course here, since you know every `u8` must be valid UTF-8, you can use [`String::from_utf8_unchecked`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8_unchecked), which is faster than `from_utf8_lossy` (although probably around the same speed as the `as char` method):

```rust
let s = unsafe {
    String::from_utf8_unchecked(
        thread_rng()
            .sample_iter(&Alphanumeric)
            .take(30)
            .collect::<Vec<_>>(),
    )
};
```

If, for some reason, the `unsafe` bothers you and you want to stay safe, then you can use the slower [`String::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8) and `unwrap` the `Result` so you get a panic instead of UB (even though the code should never panic or UB):

```rust
let s = String::from_utf8(
    thread_rng()
        .sample_iter(&Alphanumeric)
        .take(30)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>(),
).unwrap();
```

> The length of these strings should always be 30. How can I optimise the heap allocation of a `Vec` away? Also they could actually be `char[]` instead of Strings.

First of all, trust me, you don't want arrays of chars. They are not fun to work with. If you want a stack string, have a `u8` array then use a function like [`std::str::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) or the faster [`std::str::from_utf8_unchecked`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8_unchecked.html) (again only usable since you know valid utf8 will be generated.)

As to optimizing the heap allocation away, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26757837/5923139). Basically, it's not possible with a bit of hackiness/ugliness (such as making your own function that collects an iterator into an array of 30 elements).

Once [const generics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2000-const-generics.html) are finally stabilized, there'll be a much prettier solution.

Comment: I think you should mention a possible reason to prefer `Vec<u8>` to `Vec<char>`: `char` is always 4 bytes long, meaning for any sequence of ASCII alphanumerics storing chars will waste three times more memory than is necessary.

Comment: I believe const generics are partially stabilized now. Does a prettier solution exist now?

Comment: @FrederikBaetens Not yet. If you're interested, you might want to follow/upvote [this Github issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/81615) which contains a relevant discussion.

Answer (score 2):

[The first example in the docs](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.0/rand/distributions/struct.Alphanumeric.html#example) for `rand::distributions::Alphanumeric` shows that if you want to convert the `u8`s into `char`s you should `map` them using the `char::from` function:

```rust
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};
use rand::distributions::Alphanumeric;

fn main() {
    let rand_string: String = thread_rng()
        .sample_iter(&Alphanumeric)
        .map(char::from) // map added here
        .take(30)
        .collect();

    println!("{}", rand_string);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d9bf5df18cd50489d4b5540576c85f50)