# Rust: Collect result of chain into byte array

Tags: rust

I have the following two variables: `s`, which has type `Option<&[u8; 32]>` and `k`, which has type `&[u8; 32]`. I would like to concatenate `s` and `k` into a byte array [u8; 64] using the `chain` method (I'm using `chain` instead of `concat` because I've read it is much better performance wise), however, it seems I'm doing something wrong.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
fn combine(s: Option<&[u8; 32]>, k : &[u8; 32]) -> [u8; 64]{
    let tmps = *s.unwrap();
    let tmpk = *k;
    let result = tmps.iter().chain(tmpk.iter()).collect();
    result
}   

fn main() {
    let s = [47u8; 32];
    let k = [23u8; 32];
    println!("s: {:?}", s);
    println!("k: {:?}", k);
    
    let sk = combine(Some(s), k);
    println!("sk: {:?}", sk);
}
```

The error I'm getting: `a value of type '[u8; 64]' cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type '&u8'`
[Here](https://gist.github.com/rust-play/8c832be0b86efd26aa44b6f21313ccca) is the link to Rust Playground with the code above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I collect into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757355/how-do-i-collect-into-an-array)

Comment: You cannot `.collect()` into an array. The most straightforward methods are to either collect into a `Vec` and then use `.try_into()`, or use the `ArrayVec` crate.

Comment: @kmdreko But it seems that the function 'collect' doesn't work at all. I never assigned sk a type, but after your message when I try to do `let salt_with_key: Vec<u8> = tmp.iter().chain(key.iter()).collect();` I get the same issue.

Comment: You're also trying to go from `&u8`s to `u8`s, you can add `.copied()` before collecting. See it working [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=05321216925f3ce24fe6dadf1b692a08) on the playground.

Comment: If you are particularly concerned about performance, using `ArrayVec` will likely be better since it would avoid an allocation and extra copy (potentially).

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks for the playground link! Regarding the ArrayVec - can you point me to some examples how to use it?

Comment: `chain` and `collect` methods work with iterators. Copying the whole slice is considered faster than one by one element. But what you @Zive have read about `collect` is that it uses specialization to implement bulk copy on slice iterators directly. But as you are working with slices/arrays already there is no need to go with iterators

Comment: @Dawer performance should be measured to know for certain, but I upvoted your answer since its the most clear and straight-forward way of achieving what OP wants and is more likely to be performant.

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks a lot for your insightful help as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```rust
fn combine(s: Option<&[u8; 32]>, k: &[u8; 32]) -> [u8; 64] {
    let tmps = s.unwrap();
    let mut result = [0; 64];
    let (left, right) = result.split_at_mut(32);
    left.copy_from_slice(&tmps[..]);
    right.copy_from_slice(&k[..]);
    result
}
```

`slice::split_at_mut` returns two mutable slices.

And from `slice::copy_from_slice(&mut self, src: &[T])` docs:

> Copies all elements from src into self, using a memcpy.

Resulting [asm (GodBolt.org)](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/aEqfzzaP4) is easily vectorized:

```
example::combine:
        push    rax
        test    rsi, rsi
        je      .LBB0_1
        movups  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsi]
        movups  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rsi + 16]
        movups  xmmword ptr [rdi + 16], xmm1
        movups  xmmword ptr [rdi], xmm0
        movups  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rdx]
        movups  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rdx + 16]
        movups  xmmword ptr [rdi + 32], xmm0
        movups  xmmword ptr [rdi + 48], xmm1
        mov     rax, rdi
        pop     rcx
        ret
.LBB0_1:
        lea     rdi, [rip + .L__unnamed_1]
        lea     rdx, [rip + .L__unnamed_2]
        mov     esi, 43
        call    qword ptr [rip + core::panicking::panic@GOTPCREL]
        ud2
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=935cf99669904db11dc091cab1a679cc) is a solution using the [arrayvec](https://crates.io/crates/arrayvec) crate.

```
use arrayvec::ArrayVec; // 0.7.0

fn combine(s: Option<&[u8; 32]>, k: &[u8; 32]) -> [u8; 64] {
    let tmps = *s.unwrap();
    let tmpk = *k;
    let result: ArrayVec<u8, 64> = tmps.iter().chain(tmpk.iter()).copied().collect();
    result.into_inner().unwrap()
}
```